# rails 4 undesired double pop-up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-flash

In my rails 4 application session expire time set to 10 minutes for user login.

After that user clicks on any link the default flash message is comes up like `Your session is expired. Please sign in again to continue.`

This is fine, but below this another flash message is coming like "true" . I don't know from where it is coming from, how can I solve this?

---

**Application Controller**

```
def layout_by_resource 
  if devise_controller? && resource_name == :operator && (action_name == 'sign_in' and params[:login_request_forced].nil?) 
    "application" 
  elsif (params[:login_request_forced].present? and (params[:login_request_forced] == "" or params[:login_request_forced] == true))     
    "forced_login" 
  end 
end
```

Comment: have you written something in your application_controller for redirecting to a page after expiring session?

Comment: No, i didn't write anything,  i have below  methods in application controller.                                 def layout_by_resource
    if devise_controller? && resource_name == :operator && (action_name == 'sign_in' and params[:login_request_forced].nil?)
      "application"
    elsif (params[:login_request_forced].present? and (params[:login_request_forced] == "" or params[:login_request_forced] == true))
      "forced_login"
    end
  end